# 8-puzzle which has the numbers in order but has gap in between

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, parity

If the numbers of the 8-puzzle are all in order, but the blank tile is somewhere in between, is this puzzle solvable? (for example, $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 2 \\ 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 6 & 7 & 8 \end{bmatrix}$, where 0 represents the blank tile)

Comment: Is the eight puzzle the "slider" puzzle?  And the 0 is the hole.  I think the solution is possible if the gap is in a odd position, and that one is not.  I think.

Comment: Oops  I'm wrong that is solvable.

Comment: Why is it solvable then?

Comment: Because I solved it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Then how about a more general case, where the blank tile is in between somewhere of the ordered sequence?

Comment: It's been years, but if you add up the displacement of the tiles and ... well, you can google it.

Answer (score 0):

Count how far the gap tile is displaced.  In your case it has been moved up 2 and over 1.  So that is a displacement of 3.  Call that "odd" or 1.

Now do that for every square.

1 is in place.  So that's displaced 0.

2 is over 1 so that's displaced 1.

3 is down one and over 3 so that's 3. odd. 1.

4 is over 1. 1.

5 is over 1. 1.

6 is displaced 3. odd. 1.

7 is displace 1.

8 is displaced 1.

Add those all up.  8.  even.  0.

Even parity is solvable.

Odd parity is not.

$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 2 \\ 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 6 & 7 & 8 \end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 5 \\ 0 & 3 & 4 \\ 6 & 7 & 8 \end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 3 & 5 \\ 1 & 0 & 4 \\ 6 & 7 & 8 \end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 &3 \\ 4 & 5 & 0 \\ 6 & 7 & 8 \end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 &3 \\ 4 & 5 & 8 \\ 0 & 6 & 7 \end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 &3 \\ 5 & 0 & 8 \\ 4 & 6 & 7 \end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 &3 \\ 5 & 6 & 8 \\ 4 & 0 & 7 \end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 &3 \\ 5 & 6 & 0 \\ 4 & 7 & 8 \end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 &3 \\ 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 0 & 7 & 8 \end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 &3 \\ 4 & 5 & 6 \\  7 & 8 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 0):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/15_puzzle#Solvability) states that if you move the blank (I assume that is your zero tile) to the final location (lower right?) the puzzle is solvable if the permutation is even. If we slide the $0$ right and then down, we get $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 5 \\ 3 & 4 & 8 \\ 6 & 7 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$  Now to get to solved, you swap $(5,3),(5,4),(8,6),(8,7)$, an even number of swaps, so it is solvable.